# Correct syntax for filtering of geopackages (SQL)

Tags: qgis, sql, filter, geopackage

I already asked about this topic, but I am still struggling.
I created a geopackage with railways of Germany. I need to filter some sections out. I understand that geopackages work with SQL syntax for filtering. But when I use syntax I looked up, QGIS is not doing what its supposed to do.

[image]

I just want the railways without the tunnels. I used `"tunnel" IS NULL;`.

It is successful. No warning is displayed, but all the railways are gone. I use the filter function of the layer. no the query builder.
[image]

What do I have to change?

Comment: If the test is successful then the features should appear also on the map, but try if `"tunnel" NOT LIKE 'yes'` makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a bug.

If you enter `"tunnel" IS NULL;`, with an ending `;`, and click the `test` button, it will show the number of features that should be found, but QGIS won't display them

If you remove the ending `;`, then everything works fine.

PS: I see this under 3.16